# Visual Studio Code Cannot Locate .NET Core SDK

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

When I open my C# project in VS Code I get the Error message:

> The .NET Core SDK cannot be located: Error running dotnet --info: It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
> Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download . .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.

I have downloaded and installed .NET 7.0 from the dotnet.microsoft.com website. When I run `dotnet --info` in CMD, it says it couldn't find any .Net Core SDKs, but it finds .NET Core Runtimes.
I am using VS Code 1.82.2 and Windows 10.

I have tried closing and reopening VS Code, uninstalling and reinstalling .Net 7.0 (while VS Code was closed), uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, and rebooting my pc. I have also tried writing the path of dotnet in VS Code setting "Omnisharp: Dotnet Path" and setting "useModernNet" to true.
I am quite new to coding, so I might've missed something obvious, but I have read and tried all suggestions I could find without any luck.

Comment: Is "C:\Program Files\dotnet\" in your PATH environment variable for your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Based on description it seems highly likely that you have installed runtime only. Try running `dotnet --list-sdks`, if it does not find anything then follow to the [dotnet.microsoft.com](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) and be sure to download and install appropriate SDK (from the left column):

[image]

Also be sure to check out the installation documentation - [Install .NET on Windows, Linux, and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/)